# SharePoint Web Service to Query All User Profile for use in Workflow?

Tags: workflow, user-profile

I am looking for a way to call a web service that will get and return All User Profiles stored in the User Profile Manager for SharePoint 2013? To make it more specific, I am not getting a information from a specific user but would like to gather information from ALL User Profiles.

What can I do so I can do the query? I am looking at using this within a workflow, particularly, Nintex Workflows. I am looking at no code if possible..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to grab a collection of all profiles, but in many medium and large environments this would not be a reliable call anyway given the amount of data that would be returned.

Your best bet is likely to wrap some code in custom web service call to accomplish what you are looking for.  The two easiest ways to get a large collection of user profiles is to

1. Use the Search API to return people records and then loop through and get the individual profiles
2. Use the UserProfileManager.Search() method to retrieve user profile matching a particular query

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that you can do this without code.

You will need the UserProfileService Class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcuserprofileservice.userprofileservice.aspx)

or you can try it with SPD Actions like in 2010 -> here's a link how to query the User Profile Database with SPD Workflows
http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2011/04/user-profile-data-in-sharepoint-designer-workflows/